# PHP is_nan function: Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Tags: php, get, format

I want to check of there is a ean code (only numeric) in the $_GET method. And of check of that is a number. When it is not of that two i want to redirect to another page, and exit the php script.

```
if(!isset($_GET["ean"])){
    header('Location: /products.php');  
    exit();
}else{
    if(is_nan($_GET["ean"])){
        header('Location: /products.php');
        exit();
    }
}
```

When $_GET["ean"] = 234234sd (So, it is not numeric) there is a php error:
`Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in ..... on line 9`
Line 9 is the line with de is_nan function.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In, PHP `NaN` is a float.  See the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#language.types.float.nan

Because of this, `is_nan` wants a `float` as a parameter.  It will tell you whether it's NaN or not.

In your case, you want `is_numeric`.

```
if(!is_numeric($_GET["ean"])){
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you. This wil works! 
"You can accept an answer in 5 minutes"